# How to add audio to a video using sharpAVI

Tags: c#, audio, video, video-processing

I am trying to add audio to a video that I am creating from the image sequence. I am setup the [sharpAVI](https://github.com/baSSiLL/SharpAvi) as follows:

```
var audioFileName = Path.Combine(m_rootDir, "audio", "v1.wav");
m_videoFileWritter=new AviWriter(m_videoFileName);
m_videoFileWritter.FramesPerSecond  = m_frameRate;
m_videoFileWritter.EmitIndex1 = true;
m_videoStream = m_videoFileWritter.AddMJpegWpfVideoStream(data.width, data.height, 70);
m_audioStream = m_videoFileWritter.AddAudioStream(channelCount: 2, samplesPerSecond: 44100, bitsPerSample: 16);
m_audioData = File.ReadAllBytes(audioFileName);
m_audioByteRate = (int)Math.Ceiling(m_audioStream.BitsPerSample / 8.0 * m_audioStream.ChannelCount * m_audioStream.SamplesPerSecond);
m_audioBlockSize = (int)Math.Ceiling(m_audioByteRate / m_videoFileWritter.FramesPerSecond);
m_audioBuffer = new byte[m_audioBlockSize];
```

and when I am adding frames, I also add audio as follows:

```
bool AddFrameToStream(Bitmap image)
{
    var buffer = new byte[m_data.width * m_data.height * 4];
    var bits = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, m_data.width, m_data.height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    m_videoStream.WriteFrame(true, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    image.UnlockBits(bits);

    if(m_audioDataPoiner + m_audioBlockSize < m_audioData.Length)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(m_audioData, m_audioDataPoiner, m_audioBuffer, 0, m_audioBlockSize);
        m_audioDataPoiner += m_audioBlockSize;
        
    }
    else
    {
          Console.WriteLine("error");
    }
    m_audioStream.WriteBlock(m_audioBuffer, 0, m_audioBuffer.Length);
    return true;
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting the video that shows the image, I also get a small amount of audio at the start of the video, and then all is quiet.

I checked and the size of the audio files is big enough to cover the whole of the video and also I am not getting the error message (I put a breakpoint in the code which waits on the error line).

What is the problem with this? Am I using this library correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code lies in the way you handle the audio data and the audio block size. It seems like you're not updating the m_audioBuffer correctly with the appropriate amount of audio data for each frame. Additionally, the calculation of the audio block size based on the byte rate may not be accurate in all cases.

To fix the problem, you can modify your code as follows:

```
bool AddFrameToStream(Bitmap image)
{
    var buffer = new byte[m_data.width * m_data.height * 4];
    var bits = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, m_data.width, m_data.height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    m_videoStream.WriteFrame(true, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    image.UnlockBits(bits);

    int bytesRemaining = m_audioData.Length - m_audioDataPointer;
    if (bytesRemaining > 0)
    {
        int bytesToWrite = Math.Min(m_audioBlockSize, bytesRemaining);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(m_audioData, m_audioDataPointer, m_audioBuffer, 0, bytesToWrite);
        m_audioDataPointer += bytesToWrite;
        m_audioStream.WriteBlock(m_audioBuffer, 0, bytesToWrite);
    }

    return true;
}
```

In this modified code, the bytesRemaining variable calculates the number of audio bytes left to be written. Then, bytesToWrite determines the amount of audio data to be written in the current frame, considering either the remaining data or the predefined block size, whichever is smaller. This ensures that you correctly handle the case where the remaining audio data is less than the block size.

Make sure to update your code accordingly and test it to see if the audio is properly synchronized with the video throughout the entire duration.

Comment: Thanks, I did the suggested changes but still getting only audio for one frame and then the system is quiet.

Comment: @mans What happens if you replace the last line with: `m_audioStream.WriteBlock(m_audioBuffer, m_audioDataPointer, bytesToWrite);` ... Basically don't keep writing at position `0` because I suspect that means you keep overwriting the audio data at that same point...

Comment: @VC.One I am getting the error "End offset exceeds the length of data.". Please note that my code is based on these code snippets from the documentation:  https://bassill.github.io/SharpAvi/working-with-audio-streams.html